# Kotlin App wide change TextView Color Programatically

Tags: kotlin, textview, android-theme

How does one change the TextView default color throughout the entire app programmatically?
Not individual textView but every TextView in all activity layouts

Either getting the current theme and setting the default TextView Color, if <TextView has textColor="" in the xml, then leave it alone.

But if <TextView does not reference a textColor it's getting the default (for the theme)
How do I set this based on code/logic

Thanks in advance

Comment: how about adding an object with the colors you want, and a orientation change listener, and calling getColor with the reference from the object as in get/set color

Comment: error86: Sounds plausible, should you share a pseudo code idea, thanks

Comment: I just realized you can use your app themes to select the colors, this question should help you.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42139798/how-to-set-textview-text-color-to-specific-theme-color  you can of course change the theme at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the object's code:

```
object Example {
fun getColor(c: Context) : Int {
    if (someCondition) {
        return (c.getColor(R.color.colorAccent))
    } else {
        return (c.getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark))
    }
}
```

}

you call the get method every time you need to alter the view (you can store the TextViews inside a list)

Alternatively you can use the meterial theme feature that is explained here: https://proandroiddev.com/dark-mode-on-android-app-with-kotlin-dc759fc5f0e1